# page "x" may be too complex to print error

Tags: dvi, dvipdf

When I use the command `dvipdf dummy.dvi` to convert it from dvi to pdf, I get this error for some pages "x".  Could anybody help me on this please?

Comment: Is there any chance that you extract one of those that problematic pages and make it a MWE? It would be helpful for the diagnosis.

Comment: If you try `dvipdfm` instead of `dvipdf`, is it better?

Answer (score 8):

The error message is generated by `dvips` (file `scanpage.c`):

```c
endofpage:
   if (fontmem > pagecost)
      return(1);
   if (pagecount > 0) {
      return(0);
    }  /* IBM: color */
#ifdef SHORTINT
      fprintf(stderr, "Page %ld may be too complex to print\n", pagenum);
#else   /* ~SHORTINT */
      fprintf(stderr, "Page %d may be too complex to print\n", pagenum);
#endif  /* ~SHORTINT */
/*
 *   This case should be rare indeed.  Even with only 200K of virtual memory,
 *   at 11 bytes per char, you can have 18K characters on a page.
 */
   return(2);
```

You can try increasing the memory for `dvips`. It is configured in file `config.ps` (TDS:dvips/config/config.ps):

```
%   /Times-Roman findfont 30 scalefont setfont 144 432 moveto
%   vmstatus exch sub 40 string cvs show pop showpage
% to determine this number. (It will be the only thing printed.)
m 3500000
```

From the [documentation of dvips](http://texdoc.net./texmf/doc/dvips/dvips.pdf):

> `m num'
>
> Declare num as the memory available for fonts and strings in the
>   printer. Default is 180000. This value must b e accurate if memory
>   conservation and document splitting is to work correctly. To determine
>   this value, send the following file to the printer:
>
> ```
> %! Hey, we're PostScript
> /Times-Roman findfont 30 scalefont setfont 144 432 moveto
> vmstatus exch sub 40 string cvs show pop showpage
> ```
>
> The numb er printed by this file is the total memory free; it is
>   usually b est to tell Dvips that the printer has slightly less memory,
>   b ecause many programs download p ermanent macros that can reduce the
>   memory in the printer. Some systems or printers can dynamically
>   increase the memory available to a PostScript interpreter, in which
>   case this file might return a ridiculously low numb er; for example,
>   the NeXT computer and Ghostscript. In these cases, a value of one
>   million works fine.

Comment: Thanks everybody for replying. I found the problem. It was due to the a mistake in one of my figures. After I fixed that mistake, everything was fine.